# ASP.NET Web API Help Pages showing no content for odata controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have ASP.NET WebApi v2.1 installed with ASP.NET Web API Help Page v2.1

I am generating an XML file on build which is being placed in the App_Data folder, and it seems to have the generated documentation from my controllers in it.

The service is opening that XML file without any problem. I changed the name just to make sure it was in fact opening it.

When I navigate to the help page, I see the header information but no APIs are listed.

I'm assuming it's because the APIExplorer cannot find my controllers, since they are not explicitly mapped. IOW, in my WebApiConfig.cs I have ONLY

config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "Odata", getImplicitEdm());

where "getImplicitEdm" uses OdataConventionModelBuilder() to define entities and GetEdmModel() to pass the model to MapOdataRoute().

How can I get the APIExplorer to "find" my controllers?

Answer (score 3):

API Explorer does not support the OData service/OData controllers.

The (almost) equivalent support for OData comes from the http:///odata/$metadata. Note that $metadata refers only to the entitysets and not the actual controllers. So for example it will still show a users end point even if the users controller does not exist.

This article has a section on $metadata:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/creating-an-odata-endpoint

#### Edit 5/6/2015

A feature request for this feature is tracked by https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/94

Comment: It seems to me that the documentation would still be valid for data controllers -- I don't know why not. Disappointing.

Comment: That's a feature that we don't have, or is on our backlog. It's quite a different feature from the existing help page, and it's currently not on our backlog to do.

You can always file feature requests at https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Comment: Just as a note for future readers that there are two request tickets for this: [Implement ODATA HelpPages Similar to WebAPI](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2055) and [Help pages for odata controllers](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1892).

Comment: Edited the answer. The Web API OData code is now owned by the OData team, and has moved to GitHub